# cut -d, ignore delimiter in argument

Tags: bash, parsing, unix, delimiter

I have written a script that gets a variable number of arguments:

```
test.sh -i <input1> <input2> ... -o <output1> <output2> ...
```

I'm parsing the arguments as follows:

```
while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
        TMP=$(echo "$@" | cut -d '-' -f 2)  #i <input1> <input2>
        TMP1=$(echo "$TMP" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)  #i
        CNT=$(echo "$TMP" | wc -w)  #3
        set -x
        case "$TMP1" in
            i)
                INPUTS=$(echo "$TMP" | cut -c 3-)
                shift "$CNT"
                ;;
            o)
                OUTPUTS=$(echo "$TMP" | cut -c 3-)
                shift "$CNT"
                ;;
        esac
done
```

This works everytime, except for files that happen to have a '-' in their name.

Example:

```
./test.sh -i file1.txt file-2.txt -o out1.txt out-2.txt
```

Is there anyway I can force `cut` to ignore delimiters that occur within the file names?

Comment: I didn't know about `getopts` . I will have to check if it is available on the machine I'm working on

Comment: Why not countdown from `$#` and run a `[ -f "$arg" ]` over each arg before cutting up the '-' delimited arguments, then instead of running the `cut` filter on `$@`, you can run it on `"$input"` - $input being a new array variable that you construct from all the "non-file" arguments.  If this isn't solved later on I will post an example

Comment: `getopts` doesn't really work for options that take multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all this string manipulation; each argument is already a separate word.

```
while (( $# > 0 )); do
  case $1 in
    -i) shift
        while [[ $# -gt 0 && $1 != -* ]]; do
            inputs+=( "$1" )
            shift
        done
        ;;
    -o) shift
        while [[ $# -gt 0 && $1 != -* ]]; do
            outputs+=( "$1" )
            shift
        done
        ;;
    *) echo "Unrecognized option $1"
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac
done
```

---

This can be refactored a little to avoid the repeated checks for running out of arguments.

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    case $1 in
      -i) mode=input; continue ;;
      -o) mode=output; continue ;;
    esac
    case $mode in
      input) input+=("$arg") ;;
      output) output+=("$arg") ;;
      *) echo "Unknown mode: $mode"
         exit 1
         ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Your solution is simple & understandable. I seem to have complicated things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that may benefit someone.

The fact is, argument parsing is always a tradeoff, hence there's benefit in tailoring it to the application.  Here's a pretty generic solution that allows a little bit of error checking and disorder in the arguments.

It's very simple, but I have added some example output and comments, and for the sake of readability and compatibility, stayed away from complex ways to save a line or two (especially on the if statements).

### **Sample Usage:**

```
bash #> touch file-1 file3 file4 file-8 file7
bash #> argparse -i file-1 file3 file4 -c -k --q --j -r -t -o file-8 file7
```

### **Output**:

```
Input files: file-1 file3 file4
Output files: file-8 file7
Args are: c k q j r t

Doing action for argument "c"
Doing action for argument "k"
Doing action for argument "j"
```

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#argparse

#Assign arrays

until [[ $# < 1 ]]; do
#ignore args "-i" and "-o", and tell the script to check for files following
    if [ "$1" == "-i" ] ; then unset output ; input=1 ; shift 
    elif [ "$1" == "-o" ] ; then unset input ; output=1 ; shift 
    fi
#Add input and output files to respective arrays
    if [ -f "$1" ] ; then 
        if [[ $input == 1 ]]; then 
            infiles+=($1)
        elif [[ $output == 1 ]]; then 
            outfiles+=($1)
        fi
    else
#Add args to array
        arg="$(echo "$1" | sed 's/-//g')"
        args+=($arg)
    fi
    shift
done

#Some debug feedback
echo -e "Input files: ${infiles[@]}\nOutput files: ${outfiles[@]}\nArgs are: ${args[@]}\n"

#Simulate actually "doing" something with the args
for arg in "${args[@]}" ; do 
    case $arg in
        "c") echo "Doing action for argument \"c\"" ;;
        "k") echo "Doing action for argument \"k\"" ;;
        "j") echo "Doing action for argument \"j\"" ;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done
```

---

**Update/Edit**: I've just realised, that the OP didn't have any requirement for parsing *actual* arguments other than `-i` and `-o`.  Well regardless, this may still come in handy for someone at some point.